# Running an executable under Scheduled Task with web access

Tags: c#, windows, web-services, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking to find out if there are any inherent restrictions when running an executable from a scheduled task that calls a web service while there are no users logged on?

I can't see any inhernt issue if the user that the taski runs under has the correct permissions but would there be any issues connecting over port 80 to a web service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If any authentication is required for either a web proxy, the web service, or anything else, you'll need to store the password.

You will find a bit of an overview at https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run/ that covers this.